# How do i create record with this model

Tags: django

I am trying a record in this table but failed. Please someone show me an example , How do i create a record in this table using  `ApplicationStage.objects.create(...............)`

```
class ApplicationStage(Base):
    stage_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    leave_id = models.ForeignKey(Leave)
    auth_id = models.ForeignKey(ApproveAuthority)
    approve_status_id = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    approve_total_day = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    comment = models.TextField()
    approved_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_livedate = models.CharField(choices=(("yes","Yes"),
                                           ("no","No"),
                                           ),max_length=15)
```

Comment: "failed" doesn't really tell us much. Why does it fail, what error message?

Comment: you might try issuing the full_clean() method on the model instance, then catching and printing the exception.  Might provide more information on the error that you are getting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the directory to your application and run:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then import model:

```
from your_app_name.models import ApplicationStage
```

Then use the following command to create a record:

```
a = ApplicationStage(stage_id=1, leave_id=1, auth_id .......... and so on)
a.save()
```